# Android app that checks if there is an installed app to read file of different types(like pdf, docx,pptx,txt,rtf) etc

Tags: android, android-intent

This code gives the output saying .doc, .tyyt, .txt reader absent and PDF reader is present.

But actually in phone all the readers (pdf, txt, doc) are present and obviously there is no app to handle .tyyt format.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.io.File;
import android.content.ContentProvider;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final EditText t1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PackageManager pm3=getPackageManager();
            String msg=" ",type;
            PackageManager pm2=getPackageManager();
            MimeTypeMap mime2= MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            String type2=mime2.getMimeTypeFromExtension(".doc");
            Intent intent2=new Intent();
            intent2.setType(type2);
            if(pm2.queryIntentActivities(intent2,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).size()>0)
            {
                msg+="doc reader present";
                t1.setText(msg);

            }
            else
            {
                msg+="doc reader absent";
                t1.setText(msg);
            }


            MimeTypeMap mime3= MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            // I am just trying to check if it works by setting an  unkonwn file type,obiviously it should not be present
            String type3=mime3.getExtensionFromMimeType(".tyyt");
            Intent intent3=new Intent();
            intent3.setType(type3);
            if(pm3.queryBroadcastReceivers(intent3,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).size()>0)
            {
                msg+="random reader present";
                t1.setText(msg);

            }
            else
            {
                msg+="random reader absent";
                t1.setText(msg);
            }



            PackageManager pm1=getPackageManager();
            MimeTypeMap mime1= MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            String  type1=mime1.getMimeTypeFromExtension(".txt");
            Intent intent1=new Intent();
            intent1.setType(type1);
            if(pm1.queryIntentActivities(intent1,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).size()>0)
            {
                msg+="txt reader present";
                t1.setText(msg);

            }
            else {
                msg+="txt reader absent";
                t1.setText(msg);
            }


            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
            MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            type=mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(".pdf");
            intent.setType(type);
            if(pm.queryIntentActivities(intent,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).size()>0)
            {
               msg+="pdf reader present";
                t1.setText(msg);

            }
            else
             {
                msg+="pdf reader absent";
                t1.setText(msg);
            }







        }
    });


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Here is the layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"          android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"   tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Receive"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button1" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my manifest file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="shiva.com.opendefaultapp" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    android:debuggable="true"
</application>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to specify the problem that you are facing with this code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An implicit `Intent` without an action string will match little to nothing. If you are trying to view these files, please use an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`. The only one on which you are using `ACTION_VIEW` is the PDF one, which is why that one works.

Comment: It worked. It shows correct output even after reinstall and install of pdf reader. However it shows .doc reader is present even if its not there on my phone and emulator. Also it says some random file of extension  (.iopapo78k) also has a default reader. How is this possible?

Comment: @user3214431: Some activity on your device or emulator advertises that it supports `ACTION_VIEW` for all MIME types, presumably.

Comment: How do I remove that bug then? Because i need make sure that there is no app that can handle that type of file, based on this result i want to add few more features to my app. If any miss identification like this happens, my entire projects fails.

Comment: @user3214431: "If any miss identification like this happens, my entire projects fails" -- then you have a flawed project. There is no way for you to know what other apps are *actually* capable of. That is between the other apps and the user, not you. An app offering support for `ACTION_VIEW` for some file format can do whatever it wants, so long as the user is happy with that behavior.

Comment: Well !!.. Is there any other option ,like i store  some default pdf, doc, docx file and try to open them internally in the phone(without the knowledge of user) and then based on success or failure in reading those files, i decide whether that reader is present. If that is possible, please tell me how to open a file without users knowledge